# Error linking Howard Hinnant's date/time zone library

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, c++-chrono, zone

I am trying to install [Howard Hinnant's date/time zone library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) so that I can make a program that displays the time in different time zones. I am using Howard's [installation guide](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html#Installation) for the time zone parser, but given that I am still new to C++ and to programming in general, I recognize I may be doing some things incorrectly.

So far, I have downloaded the source material from GitHub, and I believe I successfully compiled `tz.cpp` within Visual Studio Code (while linking to the header files provided within the source material). I did not opt to customize the build.

I then tried to run the following sample program (provided in the installation guide):

```
#include "date/tz.h"
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    auto t = make_zoned(current_zone(), system_clock::now());
    std::cout << t << '\n';
}
```

No errors show up under the "problems" window on my console; however, the following text appears on the terminal:

```
C:\Users\kburc\AppData\Local\Temp\ccqDCN6j.o: In function `main':
c:/Users/kburc/Vol 7/Documents/!Dell64docs/Programming/CPP/KJB3programs/CLClockv2/CLClockv2.cpp:26: undefined reference to `date::current_zone()'
C:\Users\kburc\AppData\Local\Temp\ccqDCN6j.o: In function `date::sys_info date::time_zone::get_info<std::chrono::duration<long long, std::ratio<1ll, 1000000000ll> > >(std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::_V2::system_clock, std::chrono::duration<long long, std::ratio<1ll, 1000000000ll> > >) const':
c:/Users/kburc/Vol 7/Documents/!Dell64docs/Programming/CPP/KJB3programs/CLClockv2/date/tz.h:896: undefined reference to `date::time_zone::get_info_impl(std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::_V2::system_clock, std::chrono::duration<long long, std::ratio<1ll, 1ll> > >) const'       
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
The terminal process "C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Command & 'C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\bin\g++.exe' -g 'c:\Users\kburc\Vol 7\Documents\!Dell64docs\Programming\CPP\KJB3programs\CLClockv2\CLClockv2.cpp' -o 'c:\Users\kburc\Vol 7\Documents\!Dell64docs\Programming\CPP\KJB3programs\CLClockv2\CLClockv2.exe'" terminated with exit code: 1.

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

[Apologies for the formatting]

Any pointers on what I might have done incorrectly or failed to do would be greatly appreciated. Happy to provide more information if necessary. Thank you!

Edit: here is my `launch.json` file:

```
  "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "g++.exe - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file"
        }
    ]
}
```

And here is my `tasks.json` file:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

        {
            "name": "g++.exe - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
"${workspaceFolder}\\*.cpp",
"-o",
"${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: It looks like you need to link a library. What is your compile/link command line?

Comment: That sounds like it could indeed be the problem. I'm embarrassed to say that I'm not sure what my compile/link command line is. When I debug programs in Visual Studio Code, I just hit F5 and use a launch.json file (which I've included as an edit to my question).

Comment: Actually, it [sounds like](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/issues/398) Howard just includes `src/tz.cpp` on his compile command line rather than linking a library.

Comment: `launch.json` doesn't contain the build configuration.

Comment: `tasks.json` is the file we need an likely the file that is misconfigured. By default Visual Stduio Code will compile only the active file unless you modify your tasks.json. The instructions here: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_modifying-tasksjson](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_modifying-tasksjson) explain the required change.

Comment: Swapped the time tag for chrono to see if we can get a different, better-targeted pool of eyes.

Comment: I added in the code for my tasks.json file above, but the process is still exiting with code 1. I thought that I might need to add in the tz.cpp file into my folder as well, so I did so and used an edited version of tasks.json that would support two or more .cpp files (see above), but I still wasn't able to get it to work. Not sure whether or not the tz.cpp file is also needed.

I could try in Visual Studio Community instead perhaps?

Also, when it comes to adding in a library, is it normal for this library not to have a .lib folder? I didn't see one even after building it with CMake.

Comment: Normally you build a library as a separate project.

Comment: In mingw the library may have a `.a` extension.

Comment: ***after building it with CMake*** After you configured and generated using Mingw makefiles generator. Did you build the project from the command line with mingw? The CMake step should have generated a `Makefile` which you need to build separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: I was able to get the program to run as desired, thanks in part to Acorn's feedback. It turned out that there were a couple of changes I needed to make.

First, I needed to include tz.cpp within the program.

Second, I needed to edit my build command to add in not just tz.cpp but -lole32 as well (credit to denchat at https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/issues/272 for pointing this out). This could be done either within the command prompt as
`g++ CLClockv2.cpp tz.cpp -lole32 -o CLClockv2.exe`
or within Visual Studio Code using the following tasks.json file:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
"${workspaceFolder}\\*.cpp",
"-lole32",
"-o",
"${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

However, I then found that I needed to download a copy of the time zone database (the "Data only" version worked for me) from https://www.iana.org/time-zones and then unzip it into a downloads folder named tzdata.

Finally, I then needed to create a file called windowsZones.xml (available at https://github.com/unicode-org/cldr/blob/master/common/supplemental/windowsZones.xml ) and include it into the downloads folder.

Once I took all these steps, I was able to get the program to work.

Thanks again for your help!

Ken

Comment: Thanks to you for coming back for the write-up!

Comment: No problem! Thank you for your answer! The reason why I said "thanks in part" was simply that there were other underlying issues that I needed to solve as well before the code could finally run

Comment: Yeah, no problem at all! :) As some say, the devil is in the details. I am glad it works for you now. Also consider trying Visual Studio if you are in Windows (I do not use it, but it is "the" C++ IDE while in Windows).

Comment: Yeah actually I ended up going with Visual Studio Community 2019 for the version of the program that I posted on Github, since my friend was getting error messages when he used the version created on Visual Studio Code. But I'm glad this experience taught me more about compiling programs through Code

Answer (score 2):

The program compiled correctly, but it didn't link:

```
In function `main':
  undefined reference to `date::current_zone()'

In function `date::sys_info date::time_zone::get_info<...>(...) const':
  undefined reference to `date::time_zone::get_info_impl(...) const'

error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Therefore, the problem is not related to running the program, since the program does not exist yet.

The command line was:

```
g++.exe -g CLClockv2.cpp -o CLClockv2.exe
```

Which does not contain any linking flag (`-l`), which means GCC won't link the library and produce the error you see above when it does not find the symbols it needs. Usually, you also need a search path flag (`-L`), too.

---

I suggest you learn to compile from the command line before trying to manually configure an IDE like VS Code. Another option is Visual Studio which comes preconfigured with MSVC.